# Backbone js collection.create() how to only update view when server side save succeeds

Tags: backbone.js

I've looked for ages for this and have seen lots of similar posts and answers, but nothing that's exactly what I'm after. I may be approaching this the wrong way.

I'm trying to add a new model to a collection, but I want to do server side validation. If the server validation fails, I don't want the new model to be added in the (collection's) view.

NB. the situation is when I get a 200 success response code (my backend is cakephp, and cakephp receives the request and processes fine), but server validation means no save to database (i.e., I don't want to add to database because it would create an unwanted duplicate).

Here's my backbone code :

```
//
// Add the selected school as a school the user manages. 
addTeacherSchool: function(view) {
    attribs = view.model.attributes;
    attribs.school_id = attribs.id;
    delete attribs.id;
    attribs.user_id = this.model.id;

    this.teacherSchoolListView.collection.create(
        attribs, {wait: true, success: this.addTeacherSchoolSuccess}
    );
},

addTeacherSchoolSuccess: function(model, resp, options) {
    // resp is false   
},
```

In my backbone SchoolListView (this.teacherSchoolListView is an instance of SchoolListView) I have the code (in initialize:) :

```
this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.render);
```

On the server side (cakephp), I return false if I already have a 'copy' of the model :

```
return new CakeResponse(array('body' => json_encode($error_count == 0)));
```

As you can see, I'm using wait: true in my collection.create() call. What that is doing atm is waiting until the response is back from the server before adding the 'item' to the view. BUT I don't want the item added if server side validation returns an error.

Also, addTeacherSchoolSuccess() is called (which should be happening because there is no error in the req. / resp. cycle, just in the server side validation.

Any ideas on how to achieve what I'm after?

NB. I can (and do actually - though I've removed it so my code snippets are simpler) do validation client side, but I also want my server side validation to function.

Comment: Are you returning a status code error in the response?

Comment: @dizzy42 I'm not currently specifying what the server side validation issue is. so I'm just returning json_encode(false) as the response body. At some stage I may and if/when I do, I could use that to inform the user. For the moment, though, I'm interested in just stopping the new (failed) model being added to the collection/view. When I view the request response in firebug the request is "POST https://local.mysite.com/admins/accounts/add_student_school/20093" the response code is 200 OK and the Response is false. Is that what you were asking?

Comment: If the persisting model is invalidated by the server be it a duplication or invalid attributes then isn't it appropriate to return `400` or `422`? Although, I think returning `422` is semantically incorrect but it has become quite a norm these days… Anyway if you return any error respond code it will not trigger `success` hence it won't trigger your view to update.

Comment: have you tried `return new CakeResponse(array('status'=>($error_count==0)?200:400,'body' => json_encode($error_count == 0)));`  Instead of `statusCode=400` I recommend to use `422` or `403` for validation fails scenario. But in your case any non 2xx code will do what you want.

Comment: I had similar problem and it was because I had wrongly overridden model.save such that the options were not correctly passed to backbone's model.save. You can debug through to backbone code and see whats happening there.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. It seems I was approaching this incorrectly and I need to return some kind of 4?? status code. Thanks for the help. This page http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/httpmethods.html seems to suggest using 404 (Not Found) for my situation, but I need to read some more.