# Backbone collection.create: after waiting, how to receive the server response and add items?

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

I think I am asking a similar question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18203425/backbone-js-collection-create-how-to-only-update-view-when-server-side-save-su), but there is no solution there it seems!

I have asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20698911/backbonejs-collection-create-how-to-prevent-it-from-adding-items-if-there-is-an) about validation, but that solution is on the client side, but I want to do the validation on the server side.

Am I doing it wrong?

This is my model,

```
var Status = Backbone.Model.extend({
    sync: function (method, model, options) {
        return $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'server.php', 
            data: {
                text: this.get("text")
            },
            success: function (data) {
                // what can I do with this returned data? Should I send it to collection? if so, how??
            }
        });
    }
});
```

and the view,

```
var NewStatusView = Backbone.View.extend({

    events: {
        "submit form": "addStatus"
    },

    initialize: function(options) {

         _.bindAll(this, 'addStatus', 'clearInput');
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.clearInput) ;
    },

    addStatus: function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.collection.create({ text: this.$('textarea').val() },{
                wait: true, 
                success: function(model, resp, options) {
                    // nothing happens at all even though the validation has passed!
                    // what can I do here??
                }
            }
        );

    },

    clearInput: function() {
        this.$('textarea').val('');
    }
});
```

I thought `wait: true` is to wait for the server response before adding the item into the collection. So it waited (it seems), and I have some response from the server - but, the item is **not added**. So, what can the server response do for `collection.create`? how can backbone receive the response and act on it? and how to send the response to backbone's `collection.create`?

My server response is simple as this for testing,

```
<?php 
// server.php
if(empty($_POST["text"])) echo '{"error":"please enter some text"}';
else echo '{"message":"status added"}';
?>
```

I am on Backbone.js 1.1.0.

**edit**

works,

```
sync: function (method, model, options) {
        console.log(arguments);
        options.success("something");
    }
```

does not work,

```
sync: function (method, model, options) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'server.php', 
            data: {
                text: this.get("text")
            },
            success: function (data) {
                options.success(data);
            }
        });


    }
```

**final:**

model,

```
sync: function (method, model, options) {

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'text',
            url: 'server.php',
            data: {
                text: this.get("text")
            },
            success: function (data) {
                // what can I do with this returned data?
                //console.log(data);
                if(data !== 'status added') {
                    options.error(data);
                } else {
                    options.success(data);
                }
            }
        });


    }
```

view,

```
this.collection.create({ text: this.$('textarea').val() },{
                wait: true, 
                success: function(model, resp, options) {
                    // what can I do here??
                    //console.log(options);
                    console.log("success");
                    console.log(resp);
                },
                error: function(model, resp, options) {
                    // what can I do here??
                    console.log(options);
                    console.log("error");
                    console.log(resp);
                }
            }
        );
```

Comment: Are you definitely returning a 200 response?

Comment: Failing that, if as a last resort you could just listen for an 'add' event on your collection instead of relying on the success handler?

Comment: nope, no `200 response`. nothing at all.

Comment: and I have already added listenTo for the add event on my collection - `this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.clearInput) ;`

Comment: after adding `wait: true`, the callback of add event does not work any more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
var MyModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    sync : function (method, model, options) {        
        var req = $.ajax({
            // ... do your ajax stuff.
        });

        req.then(options.success);
    }
});

var MyCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model : MyModel
});

var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize : function () {
        var myCollection = new MyCollection();   

        myCollection.create({}, { 
            wait : true, 
            success : function () {
                console.log(arguments);
            }
        });
    }
});

new MyView();
```

You need to call on options.success. If I am correct options.success is the success handler you passed in from .create. So you're problem is that you're not calling it - hence nothing happens. I think in practice as well it's always good to return the appropriate HTTP status code (with your response), in this case 200 for success.

Comment: thanks but not working. I am totally lost in your code. how can I pass the form data to the server then with this - `$.getJSON('server.php', function(data, textStatus) ` for validation?

Comment: Sorry, I kind of just adapted an example from some of my existing code (quickly). Updated my example.

Comment: it's ok. thanks for the edit. but it is still no way that `.create` will receive it... :(

Comment: `this.collection.create({ text: this.$('textarea').val() },{
                wait: true, 
                success: function(model, resp, options) {
                    console.log(options);
                }
            }
        );`

Comment: check this line out -`console.log(options);` nothing is printed.

Comment: take a look at my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/w38Hj/ - all of the arguments appear as expected.

Comment: thanks. please see my edit above. i think `options.success` is not called with ajax.

Comment: got it worked by changing the datatype to text `dataType: 'text',` but the item is added to the collection regardless what I return from the server. i don't want the item to be added to the collection if there is an error from the server. is it possible?

Comment: Yes. You just need to filter your response within the success handler. (check the contents of the message). If the message isn't 'success' don't make the call onwards to options.success. Something along those lines.

Comment: yes. finally got it worked after filtering the ajax response! thank you so much!!